# Find $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_0^x \frac{t\,dt}{\cos t}}{\sin^2(x)}\,$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\int_0^x \frac{t\,dt}{\cos t}}{\sin^2(x)}$$

what does it mean when the limit of $x$ is $0$ in the integral?
How do I calculate this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, you have
$$
\frac d {dx} \int_0^x \frac{t\,dt}{\cos t} = \frac x {\cos x}
$$
and then you can apply L'Hopital's rule.